# Hide & Unhide macros won't work after locking columns & protecting sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have two columns, E & G, that have formulas in them, so I locked those columns and protected the sheet they're in. I have two buttons on the sheet a Hide & Unhide button. After locking those columns & protecting the sheet, those macros assigned to those buttons do not work anymore. When I select the buttons, I receive a run-time error '1004', unable to set the Hidden property of the Range class. 
The macro's code are as follows:

```
Sub Hide()
'
' Hide Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+H
'
    For Each c In Range("C7:C446")
    If IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
    'If (c.Value) = "" Then
     c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Unhide macro:

```
Sub UH()
'
' UH Macro
'

'
    Rows("6:447").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

I think I have to add an unprotect command, which I've tried but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried:

```
Worksheets("JE").Unprotect Password:="ImportLCPA17", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

does anyone know of any adjustments I can make to have those hide & unhide macros, linked to the buttons, work while still having those columns locked?

Comment: Yes, you need to unprotect the sheet, which can be done in your macro. I think the problem is with the UserInterfaceOnly:=True part. Set it to all. And after you're done, lock the sheet again, all in the same macro.

Comment: @LPChip so, in both the hide & unhide macros have a unprotect statement in the beginning like: `Worksheets("JE").Unprotect Password:="ImportLCPA17", UserInterfaceOnly:=All` and then a protect statement at the end like: `Worksheets("JE").Protect Password:="ImportLCPA17", UserInterfaceOnly:=All` ? Thanks for your response!

Comment: Yup, thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

To initially unprotect the sheet: 
`Worksheets("name").Unprotect Password:="password"`

To protect the sheet again:
`Worksheets("name").Protect Password:="password"`